# on scroll data load at the end of listview after on scroll method is called it takes to the first element of list

Tags: android, listview

I am using on scroll listener on list view and I am loading data at the end of list,it is getting loaded but after every scroll when request goes it takes me to first page and i want list should be stable  when i scroll and doesn't move to first and loads data.

```
searchListview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount ) {
                   // I am loading data here
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could be because you are creating a new data set container (List, Map, etc.) instead of adding newly loaded values to the existing container.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you are setting new yourAdapter on listview everytime your request is called. You need to check do that if and only if your adapter is null. If its not null then you can call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Note: Do not clear your data on subsequent calls.